# Changing a namespaced admin route into a root route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, routes

I have my Pages model, views, and controller in the Admin namespace. However, I would like to display the pages at a root level. Instead of admin/pages/[:id], I would like the routes for showing pages to be /[:id]. Is it possible to do this without creating multiple controllers and models for Pages and while still keeping Pages in the admin namespace? If so, what is the best approach and how would you have to write your routes?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and as far as I've tried, I don't think theres a way to change the routes for showing pages to be `/:id` instead of `admin/pages/[:id]` without creating multiple controllers for Pages and while **still keeping Pages in the admin namespace.** Referring "without creating multiple controllers and models for Pages and while still keeping Pages in the admin namespace", I don't understand creating a new model. Creating a new controller will suffice.

For a non-nested resource, changing the route to a root route is relatively an easy task, i.e. say `/:id` instead of `foo/:id`

**p.s.** initially, I did not give your question a deep thought, and skipped the **admin namespace** part. But, trying this turned out to be fun. I'd really want to see someone post an answer to this (this is one answer where I'd love to be downvoted and pointed towards the correct answer).